# Populating MongoDB in a loop in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async.js

I would like to populate a MongoDB database using Node.js (mongoose).  I'm trying to do it asynchronously (using async.js) after the DB connection has been made, but it's not working as I hoped.  Instead of filling the database with a small number of documents, the database connection is opened and closed before the writes can be made.  Sounds like a very typical async problem, but I am at a loss.

My code is currently as follows.

```
var runStart = '2019-01-01 00:00:00';
var runEnd = '2019-01-17 00:00:00';
var periods = [];
var d = moment(runStart);
while (d < moment(runEnd)) {
  periods.push([d.format(), d.add(1, 'day').format()]);
}

mongoose.connect(config.db);
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', () => {
  throw new Error('unable to connect to database');
});
db.on('open', () => {
  console.log('DB open');
  async.each(
    periods,
    function(period, next) {
      Period({
        start: moment(period[0]),
        end: moment(period[1]),
        type: 'delivery',
        notes: ''
      }).save((err) => {
        if (err) callback(err);
      });
      next();
    },
    function(err) {
      db.close();
      console.log('FINISHED!');
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   function(period, next) {
      Period({
        start: moment(period[0]),
        end: moment(period[1]),
        type: 'delivery',
        notes: ''
      }).save((err) => {
        if (err) callback(err); // `callback` is supposed to be `next
      });
      next();  // `next` is called before the document is saved
    },
```

Change that code to this:

```
function(period, next) {
  Period({
    start: moment(period[0]),
    end: moment(period[1]),
    type: 'delivery',
    notes: ''
  }).save((err) => {
    next(err);
  });
},
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks. I'm still struggling to think asynchronously, so this kept me busy for a few hours before I posted. Nice that I got so close! Thanks for your time.